# EXCEL PIVOT Help required

Tags: excel, pivot, transpose

i have data in following data

```
Id     Status   Value   Line
A-001   1       10      A
A-001   1       20      B
A-001   1       30      C
A-002   2       11      A
A-002   2       12      B
A-002   2       13      C
```

using pivot, i want to transpose it to

```
ID    Status    A    B    C    Total
A-001    1     10    20    30    60
A-002    2     11    12    13    36
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ID` as a Row field, `Status` as a Row field, `Line` as a Column field, `Value` as a Data field?

Comment: not working. this is adding status as one more row...

Comment: To get to look it exactly like you've illustrated, you need to set `ID` row field sub total to `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag ID and Status to the Rows, Line to the columns and Value to the Values panel.

Then, on the Design ribbon select **Report Layout > Show in Tabular Form** and **Repeat All Item Labels**. Remove the row sub-totals and the row grand total.

[image]
[image]